# Android Application Menu does not show up in AVD but in a Device

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to Android application development and I am facing an issue regarding the menu of an application.
Weirdly, when testing the application in eclipse AVD, the menu is not visible. But when debugging in a device (Galaxy Nexus), the menu is there! See enclosed screenshots.
Can't explain why!
Here's the menu code for the activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item android:id="@+id/action_logout" android:title="@string/action_logout" android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" android:orderInCategory="100" android:menuCategory="system"></item><item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" android:menuCategory="system"/>
</menu>
```

And the *inflater* is also there in the activity class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here are the screenshots!

[Galaxy Nexus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gTPC.jpg)

[In Eclipse AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfYc8.png)

Comment: Press menu button of emulator and make sure that menu is displaying or not....

Comment: Make sure that you are using emulator after 3.0 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu option doesn't shown at there because for the devices that have menu button(a physical button like galaxy s4 and dozens of other devices have) unless you explicitly add it to action bar.

For devices that doesn't have a physical button (like your nexus) that virtual button on action bar appears

Comment: Interesting, how do I explicitly add it to the action bar?

Answer (score 0):

Clear hardware buttons on your AVD definition and you'll get the soft menù back

Comment: I unchecked `Display a skin with hardware controls` in AVD settings but no change

Comment: check also in Device Definition that your buttons definition is Software